# Are an Onyx Dog’s attacks magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters, attack

The [figurine of wondrous power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/5413-figurine-of-wondrous-power) is a magic item, and therefore by the [definition in the SAC](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf), magical in a game-mechanical sense, i.e. activating it would not work in an *antimagic field*, *detect magic* would detect it, etc. It says

> If you use an action to speak the command word and throw the figurine to a point on the ground within 60 feet of you, the figurine be comes a living creature. (...) The creature is friendly to you and your companions.
>
> It understands your languages and obeys your spoken commands. If you issue no commands, the creature defends itself but takes no other actions. See the Monster Manual for the creature's statistics, except for the giant fly.
>
> The creature exists for a duration specific to each figurine. At the end of the duration, the creature reverts to its figurine form. It reverts to a figurine early if it drops to 0 hit points or if you use an action to speak
> the command word again while touching it.

What about the creature that is created once the figurine is activated. For example, the **Onyx Dog**. Would it still count as a magic item, and would its attacks therefore count as magical attacks?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate. The linked question is asking the same thing, it’s a just a different magic item doing the same thing as the figurine in this question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkovwasonStrike Thank you for digging up that question, I had not found it and it is helpful to some extent. I'm not sure it's the same though, as the BoT creates creatures that are separate from the bag itself. The bag continues to exist. Here the item itself *transforms* into the creature. The answer  also just claims that creatures cannot be magic items, without giving support of any kind. I think there is a difference, and answering this for the figurine could provide better insight into if a creature also can be a magic item, or not.

Comment: If you don’t think the answer there is supported, that question should be bountied. That is not a reason for this question to be open. It’s the same question, just a different item.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin I agree with Thomas: in both cases there is a magic item that transforms in a creature. From the bag of trick description "When the object lands, it transforms into a creature [...]"